# Is it possible to embed a command prompt in a win32 app?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

In linux and when installing packages etc. There are some installers that have a progress bar and a dos window which shows the files being extracted etc. How can i add this window to my C++ Win32 programs so that i can have it showing the tasks im doing? I cannot find any documentation on MSDN.

**Question**: How can i add a console window *(if that's what its called, sure looks like one)* in my program to show the details of the task at hand being done?

Here is a window with what i am asking.. *(personal info so I erased the details. :]*

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot embed a real console window inside another window (although a windowed process can have a separate console window).  While it looks like a console window / command prompt, it is just a matter of appearances.  What you want to do is create a sub-window/control with similar characteristics as a console window and then redirect the console output from the application(s) being run to append to that sub-window.  For more information on how to do redirect the console output in Windows, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351.

Answer (score 4):

That "dos window" is a regular edit control: `CreateWindow(ES_MULTILINE, EDIT, ...`
However, it has the font set to a fixed-width one (Looks like courier). This is done by sending `WM_SETFONT` to the edit control.

Answer (score 3):

@user995048 says "You cannot embed a real console window inside another window".  But "cannot" is a strong word!  I can run an entire virtualized computer in a window if I wish.  :)  So one can quite reasonably intuit that there are ways of doing what you say.

Sure, it is true that what you've seen are almost certainly cases of output redirection into a custom widget, designed to mimic the simple appearance of a terminal.  However...if you want to embed one application's window inside another, there are things you can look into which might fit.  Cooperative methods exist like GtkPlug, for instance:

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkPlug.html

To actually capture a not-designed-to-cooperate app's window and throw it in your app would be trickier.  But possible, just as screen captures and virtual machines are possible.  Probably best to avoid that sort of thing unless there's really a cause for it, though...

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/article.php/c277/
link. I think the solution provided is what you need.
I tried it many years ago and it worked. I have not tried it in newer versions of windows though.

Comment: link is dead :(